# coxph stratified by year

Tags: r, stata, spss, survival-analysis

I think this should be something very easy, but I can't quite get my head around it.

I have the following code:

```
library(survival)
cox <- coxph(Surv(SURV, DEAD)~YEAR, data)
summary(cox)
```

but I would like to have the result split down into the individual years.

**Here's what the SPSS syntax and solution would look like:**

```
COXREG surv /STATUS=dead(1) /CONTRAST (year)=Indicator(1)
 /METHOD=ENTER year /PRINT=CI(95)
 /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10) ITERATE(20).
EXECUTE.
```

[image]

**and the same thing in STATA:**

```
xi: stcox i.year
```

Here's the output of

```
str(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Need 'data' .... as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show us str(data) or how to construct a reproducible example the gave  "data". I suspect that "YEAR" will turn out to be a numeric vector. If it had been a factor variable you would have seen an Intercept and n-1 coefficients. The Interecpt coefficient would then have been the same as the "year"  and the other coefficients would have matched up to the year(n) values. You told the SPSS engine that "year" was an "INDICATOR" but you didn't offer the same courtesy to the R engine.

Try this:

```
data$year.ind <- factor(data$year)  # equivalent of SPSS INDICATOR
                                    # or SAS /CLASS
cox.mdl <- coxph(Surv(SURV, DEAD)~YEAR, data)
as.matrix(coef(coc.mdl)
summary(cox.mdl)
```

Comment: I've added `str(data)` above. That is my problem, I can't work out how to add the "INDICATOR" to the R command!

Answer (score 0):

R often splits computing and display of results to allow more freedom. I assume you need the predict function of `coxph (?predict.coxph)`.

There are examples at the bottom of the documentation page, most likely you want

```
predict(cox, type="terms")
```

Comment: Hi @DieterMenne, I don't think I need to go into the prediction. What the SPSS code does is just splitting it down into the years in the dataset (i.e. 1992-1997) instead of giving just giving one MRR for all years.